# Does encrypting the key with itself make it easier to crack the ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, keys, symmetric

As the title states; Is there any risk from encrypting the key with itself? EG. $C = AES(K=K, M=K)$

I'd assume not; after all, how does having the key for a safe inside the safe make it easier to pick the lock?

Comment: [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6352/1172) is a similar question for the block cipher AES.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes didn't see that one, and it and one of the answers below answer my question combined, so I'll select and mark as duplicate.